# Query exceeded resource limits. [n] CPU seconds were used, and this query must use less than [n] CPU seconds

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, resources

How can I solve this problem?

[image]

This is an image of my SQL-query:

[image: SQL-query]

This is my query:

```
select
      count(hits.context.page.path) as path_num,
      session_atrib.date as session_date,
      session_atrib.channelGrouping as channel_group,
      session_atrib.medium as medium,
      session_atrib.source as source,
      session_atrib.campaign as campaign,
      hits.event.name as event_name,
      hits.event.product.skuCode as product_sku,
      hits.event.product.name as product_name,
      hits.context.page.path as page_path,
    from segmentstream.sessions as sessions
    join segmentstream.sliceSessionsLNDCAttribution as session_atrib
    on sessions.sessionId = session_atrib.sessionId
    join `segmentstream.hits_*` as hits
    on hits.hitId in unnest(sessions.hits)
    where 
        event.name in ('Viewed Page', 'Viewed Product Detail')
        and sessions.date in ('2020-11-23')
        and session_atrib.date in ('2020-11-23')
        and hits._TABLE_SUFFIX in ('20201123')
    group by 
      session_atrib.date,
      session_atrib.channelGrouping,
      session_atrib.medium,
      session_atrib.source,
      session_atrib.campaign,
      hits.event.name,
      hits.event.product.skuCode,
      hits.event.product.name,
      hits.context.page.path
     order by path_num desc;
```

Comment: Please post the query in text.

Comment: You could check this Q: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64453469/bigquery-exceeding-cpu-limits/64453623#64453623

Comment: I also think that several computations over the data (per the info provided by @YunZhang) can generate the error; however, your query seems simple, it could be that the order of the tables in [the joins](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-performance-compute#optimize_your_join_patterns) can cause the issue. Can you set the larger table first and/or try using an intermediate table with the rows of the first join? Additionally, the same link have more recommendations for optimizing query computation.